# Insert And Find Documents In mongoDB Using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to add document to mongodb collection using Node.js with the `insertOne()` method and the then use `.find()` to get all the collection, but i get empty string. what am i doing wrong?

this is my code:

```
function connectToDB(cb) {
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/books')
    .then((client) => {
      dbConnection = client.db()
      return cb()
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      return cb(err)
    })
}

function getDB() {
  return dbConnection
}

function addDoc(db, doc) {
  db.collection('books').insertOne(doc)
}

function returnCollection(db) {
  let books = []

  db.collection('books').find({}).forEach(book => { books.push(book) });
  return books
}

connectToDB((err) => {
  if (!err) {
    db = getDB()
    const doc = {
    name: 'a'
    }
    addDoc(db, doc)
    console.log(returnCollection(db))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to handle asynchronous code with `async await`:

```
function connectToDB(cb) {
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/books')
    .then((client) => {
      dbConnection = client.db();
      return cb();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      return cb(err);
    });
}

function getDB() {
  return dbConnection;
}

async function addDoc(db, doc) {
  await db.collection('books').insertOne(doc);
}

async function returnCollection(db) {
  return await db.collection('books').find({}).toArray();
}

connectToDB(async (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    db = getDB();
    const doc = {
      name: 'a',
    };
    await addDoc(db, doc);
    console.log(await returnCollection(db));
  }
});
```

Comment: to make it an array i needed to add ```.toArrsy()``` after the ```find({})```.
Thanks!!